# What does it mean that a protocol realizes "strong mutual authentication"?

Tags: authentication, security-definition

What does it mean that a protocol realizes "strong mutual authentication"? And what does it mean that a protocol realizes "weak mutual authentication"? Can you define them formally ?

I have found a definition for "strong mutual authentication" [here](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/1716/434-MitM.pdf) on slide 36 (not formal):

> Strong mutual authentication requires not only matching conversation records: all principals’ records of the content and the order of all messages must coincide, but also matching views of the intent: all principals’ views of the purported sources and the intended destinations of all messages should also coincide.

Comment: @owlstead : The question I get is the first part of a multiple parts question , when it is asked they didn't specify which protocol it is, so I didn't think the name is important. Later part ask to prove that $CREE_0$ - nest is "weak mutual authentication".

Comment: @owlstead : I can provide $CREE_0$ - nest 's definition if you want.

Comment: OK, but I'm not sure that posting the protocol will help solve this issue; it is still unclear what the word "strong" means in relation to the protocol, we may need the context for the security claim.

Comment: Sorry, chat is not currently available, it says I have to log in (which I already have). I can see you are trying to salvage the question, and we are trying to answer, but "strong" in itself does not have any meaning. So without the particular claim, we can simply only guess. Maybe you haven't got enough context either, but in that case you should ask the authors for more detail. We want to answer, we just cannot.

Comment: @owlstead : www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/1716/434-MitM.pdf have a definition of "strong mutual authentication" : Strong mutual authentication requires not only
matching conversation records: all principals’ records of the content and the order
of all messages must coincide, but also
matching views of the intent: all principals’ views of the purported sources and the intended destinations of all messages should also coincide. This doesn't require any ad-hoc standard.

Comment: Yes, that link contains *one* definition of strong authentication. If you are sure that is the definition of strong authentication you want to use, by all means edit it into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Strong with regards to cryptographic protocol *usually* means that the protocol is secure if the underlying primitives can be proved cryptographically strong. In your case, that could be because authentication is performed using a symmetric cipher and a key that is only distributed for 2 participants.

But as indicated in the comments, "strong" depends on context, you won't get any assurances from it by itself.

Comment: In other words, "strong" and "weak" depend on what is within the scope of a particular threat model.  Biometrics, 2FA, MFA, OTPs, TOTPs, PKI-based authentication, etc., could all be part of a strong system.  "Strong" would mean the system meets all security goals, which is more than just the strength of the underlying cryptographic primitives taken separately, right?

Comment: I guess, but I would be very hesitant about assigning it even that meaning. I mean, if I was auditing documentation and it would just say that a "strong" method would be used, then I would not assign it any meaning whatsoever. It would need further clarification.

Comment: That makes sense.  It can be very problematic to justify such assured blanket statements.  I got it.